# Command failed with error 16020 (Location16020): 'Expression $eq takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.' on server localhost:27017

Tags: mongodb

[image]
My code is below

Below is the error I am getting:

> Command failed with error 16020 (Location16020): 'Expression $eq takes
>   exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.' on server localhost:27017. The
>   full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Expression $eq takes exactly 2
>   arguments. 1 were passed in.", "code": 16020, "codeName":
>   "Location16020"}

**Code**

```
db.chats.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            users: {$in: [ObjectId("5e063bcf3e484f6430ec9053")]}
        }
    },

    {

        $lookup:{
            from: "users",
            localField : "users",
            foreignField : "_id",
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    { $lookup: {
            from: "chats.messages",
            as: "last_message",
            let: { id: '$_id' },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: [ '$$id', '$chat_id' ] }
                    }},
                {$sort: { _id: -1 } },
                { $limit: 1 }
            ]
        }
    },
    ///////Fields
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            "title": 1,
            "type":1,
            "users._id":1,
            "users.first_name":1,
            "users.last_name":1

        }
    }

])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue when executing the query in Intellij 2019.3. The mongo jdbc driver version that Intellij used was v1.7.1. I switched it to use v1.6 and the query then executed normally.

You can change the driver version in the "Data Sources and Drivers" window by clicking on the "MongoDB" driver and then in the "Driver files" section, click on the "ver. 1.7.1", choose "1.6" from the dropdown menu then click Apply. You'll need to disconnect and then reconnect so it uses the new driver.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found this was the case with 1.7.3 which seems still the default version, and switching up to 1.8.3 also fixes it (or back to 1.6 as you said), so it seems an issue in all 1.7.* drivers.